# build script tcopy command to compare files (qc) on tape and on disk

Tags: bash, sh

i build a script using tcopy command to compare (qc) my files on tape and on disk. but this script doesn't work as i want it to be, i would be glad someone can improvise this script to make it work.

```
#!/bin/bash
drv=/dev/st0
    echo -n "no.y files on tape ... : "
    total_files=`mt -f $drv eod; mt -f $drv status | grep "File number=" | awk -F"=" '{print $2}' | awk -F"," '{print $1}'`
    echo "$total_files"
    mt -f $drv rewind
    for i in `seq 0 $total_files`;do
    printf -v i '%04d' $i
    echo -n --- "file${i}" - 
    tcopy $drv
    stat=$?
    echo "status-$stat : `date`"
    done
```

The output:

```
scan no. files on tape ... : 41
--- file0000 -file 0: block size 65536: 1 records
file 0: eof after 1 records: 65536 bytes
file 1: block size 65536: 771 records
file 1: eof after 771 records: 50528256 bytes
file 2: block size 65536: 762 records
file 2: eof after 762 records: 49938432 bytes
file 3: block size 65536: 1852 records
file 3: eof after 1852 records: 121372672 bytes
...
file 35: block size 65536: 1761 records
file 35: eof after 1761 records: 115408896 bytes
file 36: block size 65536: 1 records
file 36: eof after 1 records: 65536 bytes
file 37: block size 65536: 1 records
file 37: eof after 1 records: 65536 bytes
eot
total length: 2946433024 bytes
status-0 : Sat Apr 11 14:22:26 SGT 2020
```

my suppose outcome should be something like this:

```
    scan no. files on tape ... : 41
    --- file0000 - file 0: block size 65536: 1 records ... eof after 1 records: 65536 bytes
    --- file0001 - file 1: block size 65536: 771 records ... eof after 771 records: 50528256 bytes
```

Comment: Verify your script via https://shellcheck.net  `sh` does not have the `-v` option/flag in the `printf`

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: i have corrected typo !/bin/bash not !/bin/sh an have tried shellcheck.net no issue reported.